# Anyone using RailRoad diagrams generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I recently installed RailRoad gem to generate an .svg diagram of my app's models and controllers.

The rake task keeps breaking with a similar error:

```
1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-1.4.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:263:in `load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant
```

I tried the rake task on 2 seperate apps and the error keeps appearing with a different "constant" name.

Anyone using it with similar problems?

Comment: Run the rake command again with the --trace option and add the additional output to your question! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ivan, and others, try using Bryan Larsen's version from Github: http://github.com/bryanlarsen/railroad

Answer (score 2):

I'm running it without any problems (though I did have to make a quick edit as it was representing the crows feet the wrong way).

This problem [also appears to be in their tracker](http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=21153&group_id=3383&atid=12998).  I would go ahead and add your stack trace to that ticket as well.  I'm curious if it's your version of ActiveSupport?  Bur your version and the version in use are both displaying the same problem so there's got to be a similarity somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

could you post the full stack trace? I wonder if you had the same problem as me today:

```
user@laptop:11:15 AM:rails_app> rake doc:diagrams
(in /Users/ivan/Sites/lqas)
railroad -i -l -a -m -M | dot -Tsvg | sed 's/font-size:14.00/font-size:11.00/g' > doc/models.svg
railroad -i -l -C | neato -Tsvg | sed 's/font-size:14.00/font-size:11.00/g' > doc/controllers.svg
Error loading controller classes.
  (Are you running railroad on the aplication's root directory?)

/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- app/controllers/application.rb (MissingSourceFile)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railroad-0.5.0/lib/railroad/controllers_diagram.rb:39:in `load_classes'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railroad-0.5.0/lib/railroad/app_diagram.rb:21:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railroad-0.5.0/lib/railroad/controllers_diagram.rb:14:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railroad-0.5.0/bin/railroad:38:in `new'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railroad-0.5.0/bin/railroad:38
        from /usr/local/bin/railroad:19:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/railroad:19
```

I had to comment out the line in lib/railroad/controllers_diagram.rb where it looks for applicaton.rb instead of application_controller.rb as it's now called.

Answer (score 0):

I banged my head around to get railroad working finally came across [rails-erd gem](https://github.com/bryanlarsen/railroad). It woked like a charm. Would recommend it to all facing issues with railroad.